# Plim of an estimator

Tags: estimators

What are the steps necessary to calculate the plim of an estimator, when only the general equation form is given? I have looked at resources online, but can't understand how to approach this.

Comment: There's not enough information here to work out if there's enough information in your question to do it.

Comment: Use law of large numbers, or something similar. Or try to find the limit of expectation and then show that the variance goes to zero.